# Laravel Adding Textbox Values

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to add (or subtract) text boxes in a 4.2 app?

Can you also make the new total without refreshing the page? I want to add the following form text's to show the remaining balance at the end.

TotalAmountNeeded+TotalRequestFDC+BeforeSixThirty+AfterSixThirty+TotalFromOther=Remainder

```
{{ HTML::row() }}
{{ HTML::col(6,6,6,6) }}
{{ Form::formGroup() }}
{{ Form::label('TotalAmountNeeded', 'Total Amount Needed') }}
{{ Form::text('TotalAmountNeeded', '0', ['class' => 'form-control', 'data-fv-notempty' => 'false']) }}
{{ Form::closeFormGroup() }}
{{ HTML::closeCol() }}

{{ HTML::col(6,6,6,6) }}
{{ Form::formGroup() }}
{{ Form::label('TotalRequestFDC', 'Total Requested from FDC') }}
{{ Form::text('TotalRequestFDC', '0', ['class' => 'form-control', 'data-fv-notempty' => 'false']) }}
{{ Form::closeFormGroup() }}
{{ HTML::closeCol() }}


{{ HTML::row() }}
{{ HTML::col(6,6,6,6) }}
{{ Form::formGroup() }}
{{ Form::label('BeforeSixThirty', 'Amount Before 6/30') }}
{{ Form::text('BeforeSixThirty', '0', ['class' => 'form-control', 'data-fv-notempty' => 'false']) }}
{{ Form::closeFormGroup() }}
{{ HTML::closeCol() }}

{{ HTML::col(6,6,6,6) }}
{{ Form::formGroup() }}
{{ Form::label('AfterSixThirty', 'Amount After 6/30') }}
{{ Form::text('AfterSixThirty', '0', ['class' => 'form-control', 'data-fv-notempty' => 'false']) }}
{{ Form::closeFormGroup() }}
{{ HTML::closeCol() }}
{{ HTML::closeRow() }}
{{ HTML::row() }}
{{ HTML::closeCol() }}
{{ HTML::closeRow() }}

{{ HTML::row() }}

{{ HTML::col(6,6,6,6) }}
{{ Form::formGroup() }}
{{ Form::label('TotalFromOther', 'Total From Other') }}
{{ Form::text('TotalFromOther', '0', ['class' => 'form-control', 'data-fv-notempty' => 'false']) }}
{{ Form::closeFormGroup() }}
{{ HTML::closeCol() }}

{{ HTML::col(6,6,6,6) }}
{{ Form::formGroup() }}
{{ Form::label('Remainder', 'Remainder Balance') }}
{{ Form::text('Remainder', '0', ['class' => 'form-control', 'data-fv-notempty' => 'false']) }}
{{ Form::closeFormGroup() }}
{{ HTML::closeCol() }}
{{ HTML::closeRow() }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery with selectors like this:

```
$("[name='TotalAmountNeeded']");
```

After that do whatever you want with this element. For example, you can set new text:

```
$("[name='TotalAmountNeeded']").val('New text');
```

Answer (score 0):

This would have to be done on the client/JavaScript side and not on the server/Laravel side. Using something like jQuery would do the trick.